# Umbraco CMS problem: The type 'IEnumerable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I Just started using Umbraco CMS v.9 and when I try to see the page I just created it shows an error. 
**Code**

```
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.PublishedModels;
@inherits Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Views.UmbracoViewPage<ContentModels.HomePage>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.PublishedModels;
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        @Model.Name
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @Model.Check
        </div>
        <div>
            
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        
    </footer>
</html>
```

**Error:**
The type 'IEnumerable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You
must add a reference to assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'

I've been searching the solution for a while. I came across a lot of other people who have encountered similar (my assumption) problems. I tried to add to web.config something like:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

but any time I rerun, the file web.config get overwritten with the original code deleting the lines I wrote. (this thing is really upsetting me)

**How this thing can be fixed?**
Thanks

Comment: Umbraco 9 is still in beta, so if you see something not working as expected you should report it over on GitHub (https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues). Umbraco 9 runs on .NET 5 (.Net Core), BTW, maybe you are trying to run it on .Net Framework 4.x?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is v9 you are using if you have a web.config.  V9 does not have a web.config file as it is written in .Net Core.  Settings are in appsettings.json.

I think you have v8.

Also I think the issue you are facing can happen if your view / class / code is not referencing `System.Collections.Generic`

Place the following using statement at the top of the page wherever you are referencing IEnumerable

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```